# Can mmap's performance be improved for shared memory?

Tags: c, linux, performance, shared-memory, mmap

I'm writing a small program for Wayland that uses software rendering and [wl_shm](https://wayland.app/protocols/wayland#wl_shm) for display. This requires that I pass a file descriptor for my screen buffer to the Wayland server, which then calls `mmap()` on it, i.e. the screen buffer must be shareable between processes.

In this program, startup latency is key. Currently, there is only one remaining bottleneck: the initial draw to the screen buffer, where the entire buffer is painted over. The code below shows a simplified version of this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Fullscreen buffers are around 10-30 MiB for common resolutions. */
    const size_t size = 2880 * 1800 * 4;
    int fd = memfd_create("shm", 0);
    ftruncate(fd, size);
    void *pool = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    /* Ideally, we could just malloc, but this memory needs to be shared. */
    //void *pool = malloc(size);

    /* In reality this is a cairo_paint() call. */
    memset(pool, 0xCF, size);

    /* Subsequent paints (or memsets) after the first take negligible time. */
}
```

On my laptop, the `memset()` above takes around 21-28 ms. Switching to `malloc()`'ed memory drops this to 12 ms, but the problem is that the memory needs to be shared between processes. The behaviour is similar on my desktop: 7 ms for `mmap()`, 3 ms for `malloc()`.

My question is: Is there something I'm missing that can improve the performance of shared memory on Linux? I've tried `madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED` and `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`, and using `mlock()`, but none of those made a difference. I've also thought about whether 2MB Huge Pages would help given the buffer sizes of around 10-30 MB, but that's not usually available.

Edit: I've tried `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED`, which is just as slow as before. `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE` results in the same speed as `malloc()`, however that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Is it 21-28ms the first time or every time? malloc gets its memory from the same place mmap does so it's surprising that there's a difference. If you map anonymous memory is it the same speed as malloc?

Comment: Only the first; a subsequent `memset()` takes about 2ms. I'll edit the code with a clarification.

Comment: Good point on anonymous memory - I've added a brief edit to the end of the question.

Comment: does MAP_POPULATE shift the timings so mmap takes longer and memset takes less time?

Comment: Indeed, the total time to completion of the first memset remains the same however.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/mmap.c#L1529 I'm looking at what is different when the VM_SHARED | VM_MAYSHARE flags are set, and I think the main one is this balance_dirty_pages function sometimes gets called on page faults: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L1557 which may decide to slow down your process. I wonder if you write to each page individually (4096 byte increments) do some pages take more time than others? Some info found here: https://lwn.net/Articles/456904/ but this hypothesis is not confirmed

Comment: Thanks for the investigation! I've done some quick trials doing memset of a 20MiB (5120 page) buffer, in 4096 byte chunks, just printing process time at each 512th chunk here: https://hastebin.com/raw/lenuxemixu (timings are all quicker than before due to being on AC).  Looks like using `MAP_SHARED` without `MAP_POPULATE` makes it fast to start with, but somewhere around 512-1024 pages it slows down (I tried plotting every `memset` here: https://i.imgur.com/49qySqw.png, but I think the time taken to print each one is affecting things).

Comment: is that the amount of time per page or the total amount of time for that many pages?

Comment: Ah that's cumulative, this is per page: https://i.imgur.com/lXsMdyY.png. It does look like there's a pattern of slow accesses every 50-100ish pages

Comment: For comparison, here's the same thing but for `malloc`'ed memory: https://i.imgur.com/OmjR4B7.png. Looks like it's doing something in much larger chunks (2MiB?), but I'm not very well versed in kernel / libc internals.

Comment: I think the `perf` tool can measure what's happening inside the kernel and show where time is spent, but I don't know how to use it. You might consider trying it. I'm also not sure whether it will just work, or whether you'll need to set up a virtual machine with a customly configured kernel (which is not terribly difficult).

Comment: Even just running it under `time` will count the number of minor page faults, which is most likely where the time is going. If you `time` a few runs with different number of pages, you can verify that pretty easily.

Comment: For `perf`, read the manpages. They're pretty detailed. You probably want to record some combination of page faults, (data) cache misses, TLB misses, reloads and flushes. Run `perf list` to see what's available.

Comment: Good point on `time`. For 20MiB with `malloc`,  I get `(0major+586minor)pagefaults`, compared to `(5120major+63minor)pagefaults` with `mmap`, or `(0major+5181minor)pagefaults` when using `MAP_POPULATE`.

Comment: @Useless not just page faults but I am suggesting to find out what the kernel is doing in the page fault handler. It is surprising that mmap generates more pagefaults than malloc because again, they get their memory from the exact same place! malloc probably just calls mmap to allocate 20MiB (but it's private)

Comment: Perhaps for private mappings the kernel automatically loads the next 8-9 pages whereas it does not do that for shared mappings.

Comment: Pretty sure you're getting zero pages mapped in there COW and madvise only only advises the *reading* behaviour?!

Comment: Ah, I think I've found the answer for the difference. The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) for `madvise()` actually states that "currently, Transparent Huge Pages work only with private anonymous pages". It turns out this is configurable under `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled`, which is set to "never" on my system (up-to-date Arch linux). Setting this to "always" causes `mmap()` with `MAP_SHARED` to be just as fast as `malloc()`. It'd be good if there's another way to solve this, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in performance between `malloc()` and `mmap()` seems to be due to the differing application of [Transparent Hugepages](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html).

By default on x86_64, the page size is 4KiB and the huge page size is 2MiB. Transparent Hugepages allows programs that don't know about hugepages to still use them, reducing page faults. This is only enabled by default for private, anonymous memory however - thus for both `malloc()` and `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE` set, explaining why the performance of these is identical. For shared memory mappings, this is disabled, resulting in more page handling overhead (for the 10-30MiB buffers I need), and causing slowdowns.

Hugepages can be enabled for shared memory mappings, as explained in the [kernel docs page](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html#hugepages-in-tmpfs-shmem), via the `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled` knob. This defaults to `never`, but setting it to `always` (or `advise`, and adding the corresponding `madvise(..., MADV_HUGEPAGE)` call) allows memory mapped with `MAP_SHARED` to use hugepages, and the performance matches `malloc()`'ed memory.

I'm unsure why the default is `never` for shared memory. While not very satisfactory, for now it seems the only solution is to use `madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)` to improve performance on any systems which happen to have `shmem_enabled` set to at least `advise` (or if it's enabled by default in future).

Comment: Since you have such a tight target where 28ms isn't okay I assumed that you had a lot of control over the system whether your program was running. What if the user has some other programs running and that causes your startup to take 28ms or longer, is that a problem?

Comment: It's not really a problem, as this isn't performance-critical; it's only a program launcher à la rofi/dmenu. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't leaving performance on the table. I've been trying to get it to start as quickly as possible, as it's very satisfying to have it open on the same frame as you press a keyboard shortcut, and I don't want to daemonize it and hog memory in the background. I've put some brief benchmarks of hugepages on the [project page](https://github.com/philj56/tofi#bonus-round-transparent-hugepages).

Comment: always good to see someone writing efficient software. Modern software does waste so much potential performance: "What Andy giveth, Bill taketh away."